# Reveal module pattern - can't find the method

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using reveal module pattern but can't call the method.

```
$(function () {   
       $(document).on("click", '.EditBill', function () {

        editModule.EditBill(this);
    }); 
});

var editModule = (function () {

    function EditBill(object) {
        var itemId = $(object).data('itemid');

        loader.show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Bill/Edit',
            data: { id: ItemId },
            success: function (data) {
                loader.hide();
                $('#ModelPopup').empty();
                $('#ModelPopup').html(data);
                $(function () {
                    $('#editModal').modal();     
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return 
    {
        EditBill: EditBill
    } 
    }());
```

When I debug in Edge, I click the button ('.EditBill'), the message is

### >  SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'EditBill' of undefined or null

Thanks for Shyju, the answer is return and the first curly brace '{', should be on the same line! It works now. I don't understand why I have to follow this syntas, but it works.

Comment: Change the return part to a 3 line statement.`return {
                EditBill: EditBill
            }` and see what happens. First line should be `return {` and second line should be `EditBill: EditBill` and third `}`

Comment: What is your `editModule` trying to accomplish, as an immediately invoked function that's below where you want to use it? `editModule` will be hoisted up and be `undefined` until you hit the bottom of your code, which never happens because it fails when it tries to use a method from `editModule`

Comment: @DennisL I did not mean to edit the question ! i meant to edit the code in your page and try ( It worked for me in chrome. (although i get a different error about `loader` not being defined)

Comment: @Shyju, thanks for your advise. The codes in my project has the correct format and it doesn't work, the post didn't have the correct format, that's the reason I edit my post.

Comment: @Shyju, sorry I know what you mean now, the first { should be the same line as return, it works now! Thanks for your advise!

Comment: Totally works for me. See the jsbin http://jsbin.com/nowebax/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: That is what's called being a "victim of automatic semi-colon insertion". - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, thanks very much! :)